# font-face stop working when define the format

Tags: css

When I define something like this and I try to upload it to server, the font´s file is not loaded and the font-face is not perfomed in the web. I don´t see anything wrong in my code. I´m sure that the path is correct.

Let´s look at my code:

```
   font-family: 'icon';
          src: url('font/websymbolsligaregular.eot');
          src: url('font/websymbolsligasegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('font/websymbolsligasegular.woff') format('woff'),
               url('font/websymbolsligasegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('font/websymbolsligaregular.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
```

When I remove everyhting and remains just this line, it works:

```
 font-family: 'icon';
              src: url('font/websymbolsligaregular.eot');
```

Can somebody tell me what should I do ?

Comment: You are apparently referring to IE only (other browsers don’t support EOT). Which version(s)? What do the browser consoles say? Are the font files downloaded? How did you generate them, and how could we access them?

Comment: I think, you are not allowing these extensions.